# use 1 object multiple times in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make something like bookmarks, I have 1 note on the stage and when the user clicks it, it starts to drag and the users drops it where they want. the problem is I want these notes to be dragged multiple times..  here is my code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//notess is the instance name of the movie clip on the stage
notess.inputText.visible = false;
//delet is a delete button inside the movie clip,
notess.delet.visible = false;
//the class of the object i want to drag
var note:notes = new notes  ;

notess.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , newNote);

function newNote(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var i:Number = 1; i<10; i++)
    {


        addChild(note);
                //inpuText is a text field in notess movie clip
        note.inputText.visible = false;
        note.x = mouseX;
        note.y = mouseY;        
        note.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN , drag);
        note.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP , drop);
        note.delet.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK , delet);

    }
}

function drag(e:MouseEvent):void
{
note.startDrag();
}



function drop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    note.inputText.visible = true;
    note.delet.visible = true;
}
function delet(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    removeChild(note);
}
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a new note on the stage (a duplicate of the one being dragged), when the user drops the original one?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want

Comment: Some of your sample code has errors - 'var note:notes = new notes  ;
' - this should at least have () before the ;. I'll try to answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new instance of your note class when you drop, copy the location and other variables from the note you were dragging, add your new note to the stage, and return the dragging note to its original position.

Something like:

```
function drop($e:MouseEvent):void
{
    $e.currentTarget.stopDrag();
    dropNote($e.currentTarget as Note);
}

var newNote:Note;

function dropNote($note:Note):void
{
    newNote = new Note();
    // Copy vars:
    newNote.x = $note.x;
    newNote.y = $note.y;
    // etc.
    // restore original note. 
    // You will need to store its original position before you begin dragging:
    $note.x = $note.originalX;
    $note.y = $note.orgiinalY;
    // etc.
    // Finally, add your new note to the stage:
    addChild(newNote);
}
```

... this is pseudo-code really, since I don't know if you need to add the new note to a list, or link it to its original note. If you [Google ActionScript Drag Drop Duplicate](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=actionscript%20drag%20drop%20duplicate), you will find quite a few more examples.

Comment: thank you, your method worked fine. now  I have trouble deleting the new copies o notes, but will fix that myself

Comment: Glad to help. You probably want to store a reference to each new note in an array, and then find it and delete it when you're finished with it, as well as using removeChild() actually to take it off the stage. If you give each note a unique name ("copy_1", "copy_2", etc.) you will find it easier to find and remove them later.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not target the drag object in drag function and problem in object  instantiation

```
for (var i:Number = 1; i<numberOfNodes; i++) {

        note = new note();
        addChild(note);
        ...
        ....
    }

 function drag(e:MouseEvent):void{
        (e.target).startDrag();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dragging around multiple types of objects (eg. Notes and Images), you could do something like this, rather than hard coding the type of object to be instantiated.

```
function drop(e:MouseEvent):void{
   // Get a reference to the class of the dragged object
   var className:String = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget);
   var TheClass:Class = flash.utils.getDefinitionByName(className) as Class;

   var scope:DisplayObjectContainer = this; // The Drop Target

   // Convert the position of the dragged clip to local coordinates
   var position:Point = scope.globalToLocal( DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).localToGlobal() );

   // Create a new instance of the dragged object
   var instance:DisplayObject = new TheClass();
   instance.x = position.x;
   instance.y = position.y;
   scope.addChild(instance);
}
```